# Upload a file in asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload

I would like to know something .

When I upload a file to the server, when the file around 25mb i can upload it .When it's more, it looks like the response is not ending, so it's not uploading...

This is my webconfig , and on the server the time request limit is 9999 seconds ..

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<sessionState cookieless="false"/>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
 </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FolderPath"  value="uploads" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with -1 for `maxRequestLength`. -1 specifies that there is no limit.

Comment: setting maxRequestLength to  no limit, will make Denail attack, user can post huge amount of data, and will make load on the server. you can set the MaxrequestLength to some limited amount of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are hosting this in IIS 7.0 you might also need to increase the limit using the `<system.webServer>` tag in your web.config by setting the [maxAllowedContentLength](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits) value:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- limit to 100MB -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

The default value is 30000000 bytes which is approximately 28.6MB